# can bc-fips with environamnet property -Dorg.bouncycastle.fips.approved_only=true decrypt encrypted RSA private keys?

Tags: encryption, rsa, bouncycastle, private-key, fips

While trying to decrypt encrypted RSA private keys with java runtime is set with property
**-Dorg.bouncycastle.fips.approved_only=true** is throwing below error
**unable to read encrypted data: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.3 not available: requires PBE parameters**

**Tpl required**

*bc-fips-1.0.1.jar*

*bcpkix-fips-1.0.3.jar*

Sample code

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.InputDecryptorProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo;
public class TestJdbcEncryptedKey {
    // Path to the private key file that you generated earlier.
    private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "D:\\snowflake\\keypair\\fips\\encrypted\\rsa_key.p8";

    public static class PrivateKeyReader {

        // If you generated an encrypted private key, implement this method to return
        // the passphrase for decrypting your private key.
        private static String getPrivateKeyPassphrase() {
            return "rks123";
        }

        public static PrivateKey get(String filename) throws Exception {
            String BOUNCY_CASTLE_RNG_HYBRID_MODE = "C:HYBRID;ENABLE{All};";
            String JCE_PROVIDER_BOUNCY_CASTLE_FIPS = "BCFIPS";
            BouncyCastleFipsProvider bcFipsProvider = new BouncyCastleFipsProvider(BOUNCY_CASTLE_RNG_HYBRID_MODE);
            PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = null;
            // Security.removeProvider(JCE_PROVIDER_BOUNCY_CASTLE_FIPS);
            Security.insertProviderAt(bcFipsProvider, 1);
            // Read an object from the private key file.
            PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(Paths.get(filename).toFile()));
            Object pemObject = pemParser.readObject();
            if (pemObject instanceof PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) {
                // Handle the case where the private key is encrypted.
                PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptedPrivateKeyInfo = (PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) pemObject;
                String passphrase = getPrivateKeyPassphrase();
                InputDecryptorProvider pkcs8Prov = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder()
                        .build(passphrase.toCharArray());
                privateKeyInfo = encryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(pkcs8Prov);
            } else if (pemObject instanceof PrivateKeyInfo) {
                // Handle the case where the private key is unencrypted.
                privateKeyInfo = (PrivateKeyInfo) pemObject;
            }
            pemParser.close();
            JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleFipsProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            return converter.getPrivateKey(privateKeyInfo);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        PrivateKey privateKey = PrivateKeyReader.get(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.2.840.113549.1.5.3 is PBEwithMD5andDES-CBC, one of the PBES1 schemes in PKCS5. MD5 is not NIST-approved and cannot generally be used in FIPS mode (there are some specific exceptions like the TLS1.0-1 PRF). (Single/classic) DES *was* NIST-approved but withdrawn in the early oughties, and anyway it's completely broken.

I'm going to guess you or someone created this PKCS8 with `openssl pkcs8 -topk8` in an older version -- it defaulted to this scheme, which was barely reasonable when OpenSSL (then SSLeay) was created in the 1990s but retained past its sell-by date. 1.1.0 (released 2016) up changes the default to PBES2 with hmac-sha256 and aes-256-cbc, and in lower versions you can specify `-v2 aes-256-cbc` for PBES2 (but hmac-sha1 for the PRF, which TTBOMK is still FIPS and actually secure even though sha1 *signatures* or at least *certificates* are broken and generally prohibited since about 2015).

BouncyCastle can read (and decrypt) PBES2 correctly since more or less forever, but the *standard* providers in Java versions below 11.0.1 mishandle all PBES2, and even after that they don't handle all cases. If these are concerns, `-v1 PBE-SHA1-3DES` (which is actually a PKCS12 scheme not PKCS5v1, but OpenSSL lumps them together) should be good for FIPS and compatible with both BouncyCastle and standard providers.